# Notification Sound Interval

Tags: android, notifications

How to put the interval between the notification sound , when i receive the notification then , i have to put 0.5sec gap between the ring ,
here 1 stand for ring (.mp3 format) and 
.5 stand for gap .
1 + 0.5 + 1 + 0.5 + 1 =4 sec

Code : I am using FCM , in on received message i have following code , my coins.mp3 , beep for 1 second, i want to beep it 3 times with an interval of .5 second with every beep

```
Uri defaultSoundUri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.coins);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Logizo")
                .setContentText("Order Status Changed to "+messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        try {
            foreground = new ForegroundCheckTask().execute(this).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MainActivity.removeNotificationsFromStatusBar(NOTIFICATION_ID,this,foreground);
```

Comment: create custom mp3 and set as notification tune

Comment: how to set the delay ?

Comment: add handler post method

Comment: use any mp3 editor software to edit sound

Comment: I have mp3 sound with 1 second , now when notification come , then the sound will play for 1 second then it stop for .5 second ,then it again play for 1second ,again it stop for .5 second ,again the sound play

Comment: then use any music editor software to make this type of sound